# 64 bit addresses

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, 64-bit, memory-address

I compile the application for 64 bit Windows operating system.
The application should save 64 bit addresses, I have to decide about variable type, to save them. I thought to save them in long. But `sizeof(long) == 4`.Where and how can I save the addresses

Comment: What do you mean by "save"?  Do you mean you want to write the addresses to file?

Comment: Where are you getting the addresses from?  Addresses are stored in pointers.

Comment: Yep, use a pointer.  The compiler will pick the pointer size based on the compile mode.

Comment: There is no language called C/C++

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should store memory addresses in pointers:

```
void *myaddr = 0x0123456789ABCDEF; // memory address
int *myaddr2 = 0x0123456789ABCDEF; // pointer to int in memory, dereferencable
```

You can get the address of a variable like this:

```
int myvar;
int *addrofmyvar = &myvar;
printf("%p", addrofmyvar); // use %p to print pointers
```

---

**Note**: there are some differences between C and C++ regarding pointers (esp. void pointers). See the C and C++ standards. There is no such thing as "C/C++".

Answer (score 7):

If you intend to store a pointer as a number, use `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t`. They are guaranteed to match the size and the representation of a pointer.

Otherwise you are not writing portable code.

Answer (score 4):

You should use actual pointers (to whatever type is in the address) to store addresses.

Answer (score 2):

I did'nt try it but maybe with long long will work.

Please check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

unsigned long long, 8 bytes,equivalent to unsigned __int64

range: from 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

Comment: +1 to counter downvoters. This is strictly correct (or at least as correct as the other answers)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `LONG` or `LONG LONG` when writing cross-platform code. `LONG` does not have the same size on different platforms/different compilers.